# Documents4j remoteServer conversion server setup

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-boot, documents4j

I'm using Documents4j to convert an rtf file to pdf file. I don't have MS word or anything on my computer, so it seems that I will need to use a remote converter. Information here: http://documents4j.com/#/.

My project is setup with spring-boot. I went through and set up shading for maven using maven-shade-plugin based on some issues on GitHub. However, I cannot run the command that Documents4j suggests to get the server running: 
`java -jar documents4j-server-standalone-shaded.jar http://localhost:9998`

I get:
`Error: Unable to access jarfile documents4j-server-standalone-shaded.jar`.

My pom.xml file brings in the shade plugin.

Here is the plugin in my pom.xml:

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>shade</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

Here are the dependencies I am using in regards to Documents4j: (perhaps something important is missing?)

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.documents4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>documents4j-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.documents4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>documents4j-client</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.documents4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>documents4j-server-standalone</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.3</version>
    </dependency>
```

Based on what I read on the Documents4j page, it seems that the command should just work, so I assume that the jar file isn't being created.

I can't seem to find that jarfile anywhere... so I have been unable to run the java -jar command with a path instead of just a name.

Also, I was unsure about what "configuration" I may need in the plugin. Perhaps there's a trick to getting the maven shading to work? Maybe I'm misunderstanding what the Documents4j page is saying? Maybe it works differently for Macs? Maybe Documents4j isn't a good choice?

I greatly appreciate all assistance.

Comment: Does the machine you start the server on provide .NET and an MS Word installation? You need to have Word (and a valid license) to use documents4j.

Answer (score 1):

Note that it is only possible to run on a Windows Server that supports .NET and has Office installed.
https://github.com/documents4j/documents4j/issues/53